# Showing that the sequence of functions is not Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, functional-analysis, cauchy-sequences

I need to show that $ g_n(x)=x^{1/(2n-1)}  $ is not a Cauchy sequence in $C[-1,1] $ w.r.t. supremum norm. I tried to find the maximum of the difference of $g_n$ and $g_m$ by just differentiating but that did not really lead me anywhere.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If a sequence is Cauchy, it converges. That might be easier to check than to apply the definition directly.

Comment: It's sufficient to prove that $g_n$ doesn't converge to "pointwise limit" uniformly .

Comment: The supremum is $2$ independently of $n$ and $m$. Think of the edge $(-1)$ . ($2n-1$ is odd.)

Comment: Prove that with the supremum norm, if $$ f(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
1 & \text{ if $x\neq 0 $} \\ 
\\
0& \text{ if $x=0$}
\end{array} \right. $$
then $g_n \to f$ w.r.t supremum norm, however $f \not\in C[-1,1]$, then of course, since $g_n$ dose not converge in $C[-1,1]$, it can not be Cauchy.

Comment: Nice method Alonso. But to do that don't we need to assume that C[-1,1] is Banach?

Comment: @Shorty Yes of course, is well known that $C[a,b]$ is Banach w.r.t the supremum norm. Are you not allowed to used this fact ?

Comment: I may not be in the exam since we have not proved it in the lectures :( But thanks anyway and thx to zoli. I got the point now.

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín Since $f$ is not continuous, $g_n\to f$ with supremum norm is impossible.

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the [graphs](https://www.google.fr/search?q=x,+x%5E%281/3%29,+x%5E%281/5%29,+x%5E%281/7%29&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=3TI3Vr3mIYKFauXkougH#q=x%2C+x%5E%281%2F3%29%2C+x%5E%281%2F15%29%2C+x%5E%281%2F99%29) of $x^{1/n}$ for some large values of $n$, you should see a clear pattern in their behavior on $[0, 1]$: it looks as though they converge *pointwise* to:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0\ \text{ if $x=0$} \\ 1\ \text{ else} \end{cases}$$

Of course with odd $n$ we get symmetrical behavior on $[-1, 0]$. Note that this convergence is *pointwise*, and *not* with respect to the supremum norm. Now, as pointed out in the comments, if you can show that $g_n$ does not converge, you will show that it is not Cauchy, so this suggests a plan of attack. If you remember the following fact, you can use what I've said to prove that $g_n$ does not converge w.r.t. the supremum norm:

> If $f_n$ converges to $f$ w.r.t. the supremum norm, then $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$.

Comment: I do not understand the argument: here the sequence of functions does converge pointwise.

Comment: @Did Exactly, and if it converged w.r.t. the supremum norm, it would have to converge to the same limit.

Comment: Right, so the argument $P\implies Q$ cannot show the sequence does not converge uniformly (that is, $\lnot P$) since it does converge pointwise (that is, $Q$).

Comment: @Did I'm thinking of a different argument than just taking the contrapositive. If $g_n$ converged uniformly to $g$, then it would converge pointwise to $g$, thus $g=f$, but we know that $g_n$ does *not* converge pointwise to $f$.

Comment: Precisely why the argument in your post is wrong: *we know that $g_n$ converges pointwise to $f$*.

Comment: Sorry, typo: I meant to write "we know that $g_n$ does *not* converge uniformly to $f$".

Comment: So, once the typo is corrected, what is left of the argument?

Comment: @Did Assume $g_n$ converges uniformly at all, say to $g$. Then it converges pointwise to $g$, thus $g=f$. So $g_n$ converges uniformly to $f$. Contradiction.

Comment: Thus we are left with the task of showing that the convergence $g_n\to f$ is not uniform? And this task is nowhere performed in your answer, am I right?

Comment: @Did I stated it, but I left the proof to the reader.

Comment: But this is the main task one has to perform to answer this??

Comment: @Did The main to task is to show $g_n$ does not converge uniformly *at all*. Here this is reduced to showing that $g_n$ specifically does not converge uniformly to $f$.